# Should we have a "nonlinear multilevel analysis" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

The title basically tells it.  Multilevel models are pretty popular as a question topic and it might be good to have a separate tag for the nonlinear type. But I'm not sure if it's needed.

---

Link to the created tag wiki: [nonlinear-multilevel-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonlinear-multilevel-analysis)

Comment: You see a  case, and at worst tags that are not used much don't seem any kind of problem, so I say "Go for it!".

Comment: At a minimum, if you create one, be sure to make a good wiki excerpt for it to guide its usage.

Comment: Peter, could you at least show how many questions on this topic have appeared over the past month or so? Albeit I am not acquainted well with the topic, I agree with you but would have a better insight if we get the numbers (not that it is directly related to the aptness of the tag, but still).

Comment: The fact that a tag might be rarely used shouldn't itself be a deterrent.  In fact tags that are very often used can be problematic too, because there is so much stuff to look at, although scanning by votes can help.

Comment: If the new tag stays at 1 for half a year, it will be removed, so at least try to find a few other posts to retag

Comment: Agreed with every word @NickCox. As I said,  this should not be the core factor for assessing the creation of the tag. I only wanted to know the frequency which can be partly relevant.

Comment: I added the tag and a brief Wiki.  I'll try to find some more examples.

Comment: @PeterFlom, I have added the link to the tag, you created in the post.

Comment: The tag description says *the dependent variable is not continuous*, but the tag's name does not reflect that. What tag should be used for nonlinear multilevel analysis where the dependent variable is continuous? Perhaps it would be good to include guidance on this in the tag description?

Comment: @RichardHardy Can you add that? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterFlom, I could add that, but first I need an answer to my question. Otherwise I do not know what to add.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am not sure of the answer.  Maybe we need to revise the "not continuous"?  What case of nonlinear MLM with a continuous DV are you thinking of?

Comment: I don't know. I was just guessing that they exist. What type of models with discrete dependent variable do you have in mind under the new tag (if *discrete* is what you mean by *not continuous*)?

Comment: Logistic (either regular, or multinomial, or ordinal) or a count model.  Maybe others as well.